# Pegar Índice da Linha clicada com o botão direito, remover a opção de selecionar no datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

antes de tudo obrigado pelo tempo de vocês.

Tenho uma dúvida:

Tenho um **DataGridView** dgvPessoa preenchido com um **DataTable**.

Exemplo:

[image: dgvPessoa]

Quero que selecione quando clicar com o botão direito e não esquerdo, e pegar o index da linha clicada.

Método para mudar a cor da linha clicada:

```
private void PintarFundoDGV(DataGridView dgv, linhaClicada)
{
    if (dgv.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Transparent)
    {
        dgv.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dgv.Rows[linhaClicada].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = 
        Color.Transparent;
    }
}
```

Iria mudar a cor no evento de click com o mouse com o botão direito.
Pegar o `id` e chamar o método

```
private void dgvLocacao_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if (dgvLocacao.CurrentCell == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            id = dgvLocacao.Rows[dgvLocacao.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[ID_LOCACAO.Name].Value.toInt32();
            PintarFundoDGV(dgvMeuDataGridBiew, id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá @Gustavo. Poste o código que está a utilizar, será mais fácil conseguirmos ajudar.

Comment: Então, não consegui remover a parte de tirar a seleção com esquerdo.
Não quero selecionar, apenas clicar na linha com o botão direito que abri-rá um **ContexMenuStrip** e a linha ficará vermelha, para pintar o fundo utilizo este método:

>   private void PintarFundoDGV(DataGridView dgv)
        {
            if (dgv.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Transparent)
            {
                dgv.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

Comment: Edite a sua questão e coloque lá o código estruturado. Em comentário é difícil perceber a sequência.

Comment: Espero que possa entender 
Acho que ainda está confuso 
Acho que o que quero é simples, mas não faço ideia de como fazer

Answer (score -1):

Voce deve setar:
dgvLocacao.FullRowSelect = true;

`//No evento que voce subscreveu irá usar algo assim:
if (SuaDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    Int32 id = dgvLocacao.Rows[dgvLocacao.SelectedRows[0].Cells[ID_LOCACAO.Name].Value.toInt32();
}`